# How to know how much processes are running?

Tags: shell, process, centos

From a first sight it looks like a very simple question.

But Google did not help.

What I'd like to understand is how to use command line in Linux (CentOS) to see HOW MUCH PROCESSES are running ?

Not "what processes" - but just a general quantity of running processes.

I mean - we enter a command in shell and have an answer something like

Total running processes = 258

That's all.
Thanks for a hint !

Comment: superuser might be a better choice/chance for this question to be asked (if you want to do it via shell commands, and not programatically)

Answer (score 1):

to see how many processes are running use

```
 ps -ef | wc -l
```

To see which processes are using the most CPU, use `top`.

**edit**

And to follow up on pensnarik's completely correct comment, here is completely correct count

```
psCount=$(ps -ef | wc -l)
# (( psCount -- ))
# if you don't want to count the `ps -ef`, then use this
(( psCount -= 2 ))
echo $psCount
```

Please test this on  your Centos and put any error messages as a comment. I will write up a total bourne shell version (if I have to ;-) ).

IHTH

Comment: @serge : I'm glad that helped. If you found that solved your problem, please accept it as the answer, so other's don't spend time writing an answer. You do that by clicking the check-mark in between the up-and-down arrows at the outside left of my answer. Good luck.

Comment: thanks again @shelter ! I've used your last idea in a simple bash script - and it also works :) so your answer is the best for me.

Comment: The count is still not "completely correct". `wc` might or might not already be launched when `ps` is run so there is no 100% reliable way to get the precise number of processes with this pileline approach.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of shellter is almost right, but please don't forget to substract 1 from result in case of ps result containts title like this:

```
[mutex@thinkpad 1c]$ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:04 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:21 [rcu_preempt]
root         8     2  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root         9     2  0 Mar09 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
```

Comment: yes, pesnarik. thanks I've edited my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

While it answers the question, processing `ps -ef` output is not optimal.

- given the fact only the number of output lines is of interest here, there is no point to use the `-f` option, `ps -e` is sufficient.
- as already stated, `ps` outputs a summary line so it must be substracted from the line count. This can be avoided by using `ps -eo pid=`.
- as already stated too, the `ps` command itself must be substracted too, and perhaps the `wc` command, and probably the shell running your script if it is not either a shell function or directly run on the command line.

Here is an alternate solution that avoid most of these issues:

```
processCount() {
    set $(echo /proc/[1-9]*)
    echo Total running processes = $#
}
```

Being based on shell builtins (`set` and `echo`), it doesn't run any external command outside a subshell so should be faster and use less resources.

Here is how it works:

- The first line is setting the argument list with all file names starting with a number under the `/proc` directory. Each of these directories is corresponding to a process.
- The second line is displaying the number of elements in the argument list which is precisely the number of processes.

Should you want to compute that in a schell script without messing with the argument list you can use this slightly more complex approach which uses an array variable instead of the argument list:

```
set p=( $(echo /proc/[1-9]*) )
echo Total running processes = ${#p[@]}
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about `/proc/[1-9]*`. Good call. Thanks for sharing.